# tqdm not showing bar

Tags: python, tqdm

I'm using the tqdm library and it doesn't give me the progress bar, instead it gives me output that looks like this where it just tells me the iteration:

`251it [01:44,  2.39it/s]`

Any idea why the code would do this? I thought it was maybe because I was passing it a generator but then again I've used generators in the past that have worked. I've never really messed with tdqm formatting before. Here is part of the source code:

```
train_iter = zip(train_x, train_y) #train_x and train_y are just lists of elements
....
def train(train_iter, model, criterion, optimizer):
    model.train()
    total_loss = 0
    for x, y in tqdm(train_iter):
        x = x.transpose(0, 1)
        y = y.transpose(0, 1)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        bloss = model.forward(x, y, criterion)   
        bloss.backward()
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm(model.parameters(), args.clip)
        optimizer.step()        
        total_loss += bloss.data[0]
    return total_loss
```

Comment: hope train_iter is a iterable and not None. Try checking train_iter data and its type.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`tqdm` needs to known how many iters will be performed (the total amount) to show a progress bar.

You can try this:

```
from tqdm import tqdm

train_x = range(100)
train_y = range(200)

train_iter = zip(train_x, train_y)

# Notice `train_iter` can only be iter over once, so i get `total` in this way.
total = min(len(train_x), len(train_y))

with tqdm(total=total) as pbar:
    for item in train_iter:
        # do something ...
        pbar.update(1)
```

Comment: Same issue here, iterating over resultset from psql.

Comment: For my case, I made a mistake on the `total` value, tqdm `update` pass the total, the bar flash across, then fallback to this style: `251it [01:44,  2.39it/s]`

Comment: Confirming what @xiaobing says, if the total is exceeded, tqdm will fallback to that style. Watch out, the total may end up being a negative number due to an overflow, so if tqdm instantly reverts check that.

Answer (score 15):

Filling the "total" parameter with length worked for me. Now the progress bar appears.

```
from tqdm import tqdm

# ...
for imgs, targets in tqdm( train_dataloader, total=len(train_dataloader)):
   # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

@Dogus's answer is more natural use of tqdm, but you need to make sure that your data loader (if it is a custom iterator) also exposes the **len** method.